# Можно ли менять запрос в DataTableAdapter или выполнить SqlCommand, получив в ответ DataTable? Из C# в SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Строка запроса изменяется динамически, но всегда ожидается ответ с одной шапкой.

```
DataGridView v = new DataGridView();
char[] delimiterChars = { '=', ';' };
string dbCdBuffName = PAMD.Properties.Settings.Default.CO_BUFF_DB_ConnectionString.Split(delimiterChars)[3];
string bdMDMName = PAMD.Properties.Settings.Default.MDM_DB_ConnectionString.Split(delimiterChars)[3];
string queryString = //Здесь формируется запрос
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(PAMD.Properties.Settings.Default.CO_BUFF_DB_ConnectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    v.DataSource = command. //Тут как-нибудь execute чтобы вернулся DataTable
    connection.Close();
}
```

В комментарии втором вот что-то вставить бы.

Comment: Так нельзя. Можно так  `DataTable dt =  new DataTable(); new SqlDataAdapter(command).Fill(dt); v.DataSource =dt;` dt - будет копия таблицы в памяти - и соиденение можно закрывать.

Comment: Если так уж часто такая конструкция - как вариант - создавайте свой самописный IEnumerable - f(x) и делайте `v.DataSource = new f(command);`, или сделайте функцию типа `DataTable CmdToDt(SqlCommand arg)`